# How to add timeslots per date in a df in R

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I want to generate a dateframe that has a range of dates and times. In the first column I want the date, and the second should have the times per date (from 08:00 to 17:00)

I've started by creating a dates df like this:

```
data <- seq(as.Date("2020-08-10"), by = "day", length.out = 10)
df <- data.frame(data, place1 = 0, place2 = 0)
```

Now I want to add want to add 10 time-rows per date (08:00 to 17:00). I was thinking about doing it with an apply function, but I can't seem to figure it out.

So basically I want the dataframe to look like this:

```
Date       |     Time     |     Place1     |   Place 2
20-08-10   |     08:00    |      0         |     0
20-08-10   |     09:00    |      0         |     0
....
20-08-10   |     16:00    |      0         |     0
20-08-10   |     17:00    |      0         |     0
21-08-10   |     08:00    |      0         |     0
21-08-10   |     09:00    |      0         |     0
....
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's far easier to work in date-times than it is to have separate date and time columns. Think about how you would get the times between two consecutive rows. This is trivial if your dates and times are in a single date-time column, but it you look at the (correct) answer that @jay.sf has given, the times need to be stored as characters then re-converted every time you want to do any analysis on them or plot them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using `expand.grid`.

```
dat <- expand.grid(date=data, time=sprintf("%02d:00", 8:17))
dat <- dat[order(dat$date), ]

dat[1:12, ]
#          date  time
# 1  2020-08-10 08:00
# 11 2020-08-10 09:00
# 21 2020-08-10 10:00
# 31 2020-08-10 11:00
# 41 2020-08-10 12:00
# 51 2020-08-10 13:00
# 61 2020-08-10 14:00
# 71 2020-08-10 15:00
# 81 2020-08-10 16:00
# 91 2020-08-10 17:00
# 2  2020-08-11 08:00
# 12 2020-08-11 09:00
```

however, as *@Allan Cameron* already pointed out in comments, it's probably better to use `as.POSIX` format which combines date and time:

```
dates <- as.POSIXct(seq(0, 60^2*24*10, 60^2), origin="2020-08-10")
dates <- dates[as.numeric(strftime(dates, "%H")) %in% 7:17]
head(dates, 13)
# [1] "2020-08-10 07:00:00 CEST" "2020-08-10 08:00:00 CEST"
# [3] "2020-08-10 09:00:00 CEST" "2020-08-10 10:00:00 CEST"
# [5] "2020-08-10 11:00:00 CEST" "2020-08-10 12:00:00 CEST"
# [7] "2020-08-10 13:00:00 CEST" "2020-08-10 14:00:00 CEST"
# [9] "2020-08-10 15:00:00 CEST" "2020-08-10 16:00:00 CEST"
# [11] "2020-08-10 17:00:00 CEST" "2020-08-11 07:00:00 CEST"
# [13] "2020-08-11 08:00:00 CEST"
```